# 2 input boxes, how to update the second value depending on the first and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code in my jsx file

```
const [DataOne, setDataOne] = useState(null);
const [DataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState(null);
const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

function getValueOne(val) {
    setDataOne(val.target.value)
    console.log(val.target.value);
}
function getValueTwo(val) {
    setDataTwo(val.target.value)
    console.log(val.target.value);
}
const onFocus = () => setFocused(true);

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <select>
                <option value={0}>Currency to send:</option>
                <option value={1}>Dollar</option>
                <option value={2}>Euro</option>
                <option value={3}>Pound</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select>
                <option value={0}>Currency to receive:</option>
                <option value={1}>Dollar</option>
                <option value={2}>Euro</option>
                <option value={3}>Pound</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input 
                type={'number'} 
                placeholder={'Fruit in'} 
                onChange={getValueOne} 
                value={DataTwo === null ? 0 :  (focused ? DataTwo / 2 : DataOne)}
                onFocus={onFocus}
            ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input 
                type={'number'} 
                placeholder={'Fruit out'}
                onChange={getValueTwo} 
                value={DataOne === null ? 0 : (focused ? DataOne / 2 : DataTwo)}
            ></input>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

I need to send a request to api after after each change in the input field (both of them) as follows -
exchangerate-api.com?from=USD?to=EUR?val=100 (response: 94.67)
where val is a value of one of input boxes, response should fill the second input field.
Now I just try to update the remaining input box value (This is an intermediate step before I'll start to implement api fetch),
like if I type 1, 2 should appear in the second box.
If I type 2 in the second box, 1 should appear in the first.

So far I can see that the values are changing, but things are not going as planned, not even close.
Very unpredictable.

How can I update the opposite input value wherever I change the number?

You can see complex logic here
value={DataOne === null ? 0 : (focused ? DataOne / 2 : DataTwo)}
But it dosen't work, I just tried to make previous version work, here it is
value={DataOne === null ? : DataTwo)}
Obvious
value={DataOne}
Doesn't work too.
I certainly switched DataOne to DataTwo for the opposite input box every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this problem a teensy bit differently. As you mentioned, the logic is a bit complex, why calculate it in the value, when you can just calculate it in the onChange function?

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [DataOne, setDataOne] = useState(null);
    const [DataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState(null);
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    
    function getValueOne(val) {
        setDataOne(val.target.value);
        setDataTwo(val.target.value * 2);// If you put 1 in, put 2 for value 2
        console.log(val.target.value);
    }
    function getValueTwo(val) {
        setDataTwo(val.target.value);
        setDataOne(val.target.value / 2);// If you put 2 in, put 1 for value 1
    }
    const onFocus = () => setFocused(true);
    
    // Now your DataOne and DataTwo values are calculated, so just plug them in their respective spots
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value={0}>Currency to send:</option>
                    <option value={1}>Dollar</option>
                    <option value={2}>Euro</option>
                    <option value={3}>Pound</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value={0}>Currency to receive:</option>
                    <option value={1}>Dollar</option>
                    <option value={2}>Euro</option>
                    <option value={3}>Pound</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                    type={'number'} 
                    placeholder={'Fruit in'} 
                    onChange={getValueOne}
                    value={DataOne}
                    onFocus={onFocus}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                    type={'number'} 
                    placeholder={'Fruit out'}
                    onChange={getValueTwo}
                    value={DataTwo}
                ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

This way, you do the calculations you need to do whenever an input changes

Comment: Thank you! I going to try it, I'll text whether it was successful or not. But, in advance,  this solution and your description looks confident

Comment: Your code works perfect! Thanks, but as I said earlier this is an intermediate step, before I'll implement api calls. So I did that, and stumbled upon a new problem, still React, here it is 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466172/react-calculator-is-always-late

Comment: May be you could help me again